# Encryption in python and decryption in vb.net not working

Tags: python, vb.net, encryption

I have this requirement where I need to encrypt a dictionary in python using password based AES256 encryption. I was only given a sample vb.net project by my boss to take reference from regarding the steps that I need to follow for encryption but I am not really aware of how vb.net works. I have converted as much code from vb.net to python as much I could but still the output that my code produces is different from the vb.net project. Can someone please explain what exactly am I missing out on due to which the encryption output of my python program is different than the encryption output of the vb.net program? Thanks in advance!

Here is the vb.net code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Net.Security

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        loginrequest()

    End Sub
    Private Sub loginrequest()
        Dim lobjLogin As New loginrequest
        lobjLogin.jsonProperty1 = "jsonProperty1"
        lobjLogin.jsonProperty2 = "jsonProperty2"
        lobjLogin.jsonProperty3 = "jsonProperty3"
        lobjLogin.jsonProperty4 = "jsonProperty4"
        Dim lRequestJson As String = ""
        lRequestJson = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(lobjLogin)
        Dim lchecksum As String = EncryptText(lRequestJson, "key")
    End Sub




    Public Function EncryptText(pInput As String, password As String) As String
        Dim bytesToBeEncrypted As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GenerateSHA256String(pInput))
        Dim passwordBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
        passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes)
        Dim bytesEncrypted As Byte() = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes)
        Dim result As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted)
        Return result
    End Function
    Private Function AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted As Byte(), passwordBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim encryptedBytes As Byte() = Nothing
        Dim saltBytes As Byte() = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, _
            7, 8}

        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using AES As New RijndaelManaged()
                AES.KeySize = 256
                AES.BlockSize = 128

                Dim key = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000)
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8)
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8)

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

                Using cs = New CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length)
                    cs.Close()
                End Using
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return encryptedBytes
    End Function
    Private Function GenerateSHA256String(ByVal inputString) As String
        Dim sha256 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString)
        Dim hash As Byte() = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes)
        Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
            stringBuilder.Append(hash(i).ToString("X2"))
        Next
        Return stringBuilder.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
Public Class loginrequest
    Public Property jsonProperty1 As String
    Public Property jsonProperty2 As String
    Public Property jsonProperty3 As String
    Public Property jsonProperty4 As String
End Class
```

Here is the corresponding python code that I wrote

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
import hashlib, json 


payload = {
    "jsonProperty1": "jsonProperty1",
    "jsonProperty2": "jsonProperty2",
    "jsonProperty3": "jsonProperty3",
    "jsonProperty4": "jsonProperty4",
}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
bytesToBeEncrypted = hashlib.sha256(payload.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key, interactions=1000):
        self.bs = AES.block_size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
        self.interactions = interactions

    def pkcs7padding(self, data, block_size=16):
        if type(data) != bytearray and type(data) != bytes:
            raise TypeError("Only support bytearray/bytes !")
        pl = block_size - (len(data) % block_size)
        return data + bytearray([pl for i in range(pl)])

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        import os

        raw = "".join([x.upper() for x in bytesToBeEncrypted])
        keyiv = PBKDF2(self.key, os.urandom(8), 48, self.interactions)
        key = keyiv[:32]
        iv = keyiv[32:48]

        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encoded = raw.encode("utf-8")
        encodedpad = self.pkcs7padding(encoded)
        ct = cipher.encrypt((encodedpad))

        cip = base64.b64encode(ct)
        print(cip, len(cip))


enc = AESCipher("key")
dec = enc.encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted)
```

Please note that I took some reference from some other threads as well regarding my python code because encryption is a new concept for me.
P.S. I also found out that the vb.net code is using .toString("X2") to generate a hexadecimal string in uppercase but unfortunately, I was not able to find the corresponding equivalent in python for the same. Could that be a problem?

Comment: That's not C# code

Comment: that's vb.net code, not c#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: You are encrypting on one system and decrypting on another.  A common problem is mismatched defaults between the two systems.  You have to explicitly set all the defaults on the decoding system to match the settings on the encoding system.  Crypto is designed to fail if they do not match.

Comment: I understand. But the problem is there is a vb.net service that I need to make an API call to and that service is going to decrypt my encrypted string for authentication purposes. I cant make any changes on the vb.net code because I don't have access to the same. They only provided me with a sample vb.net project so that I can read through it and get a gist of the encryption steps.